# Capitalizing the name of a specific Theorem

Tags: academic-writing

What is the standard criteria of capitalizing the theorem names when writing a paper? Consider, for example, the [*Unique Games Conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_games_conjecture). There are the following three possibilities of writing it (or probably more):

1. Unique Games Conjecture
2. unique games conjecture
3. Unique Games conjecture

Since ''Unique Games Conjecture'' is a proper noun, it should be capitalized. However, at many places, I have seen it in lower case letters only. For example, in a well-known book: [The Design of Approximation Algorithms](https://www.designofapproxalgs.com/book.pdf) by Williamson and Shmoys, it is given in lower case letters everywhere.

I also checked the book: [Mathematical Writing](https://jmlr.org/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf) by Knuth *et al.*. However, they did not discuss this issue. Moreover, they themselves have used it inconsistently in their text, for example: "Sierpinski’s **theorem**" and "Fermat’s **Last** **Theorem**".

What criteria is standard (or popular) that can/should be followed? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to know the standards for writing a paper, wouldn't it make more sense to look at other papers rather than books? Regardless, I suspect you won't find a consensus. Consistency within your own work is probably the best you can hope for.

Comment: On this particular example of the UGC, and from a very quick look, it seems to be about 50:50 between your options 1 and 2, although I didn't check for consistency within a given paper or between papers by the same author(s). I see no examples of 3.

Comment: @DM_with_secrets Please check [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/62919858.pdf) paper for option 3.

Comment: Thanks - that only adds to my initial suspicion that there is no standard, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, words like 'theorem' or 'conjecture' would not be capitalized; they are common nouns, not proper nouns. However, in some particularly notable cases the term has become part of a proper noun *phrase* : e.g., the Theory of Evolution, Fermat's Last Theorem, Newton's Theory of Gravitation, etc. In those cases it is correct to capitalize, because the phrase as a whole refers to a singular, specific thing. Further, we sometimes run across authors whose native language is German, and Germans capitalize *all* nouns. That peculiarity isn't always caught by editors or translators, so errant capitalization can creep in.

As with most things, use your best judgement, and trust that your editors and readers are competent. It doesn't have to be perfect or perfectly consistent. It only has to be effective at conveying what you mean to convey.